# how to pass string along with URL

Tags: python

I need to pass output from the query as a string along with URL how can i achieve this

my part of code is

```
cur.execute("SELECT logs.id from logs");

temp_list.append(str('https://qwetest.seem.nsww-rdnewww.net/logs/' + logs_id[logs_id_counter]))
```

here in temp_list.append i need to pass url which should consists of logs id which i fetched from the query

how can i achieve this please help me

advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue, why not loop through the IDs and use string interpolation to generate the URL? Note the `f` in front of the string to denote that it is formatting with the curly braces.

```
logs_id = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temp_list = []

for id in logs_id:
    temp_list.append(f"https://qwetest.seem.nsww-rdnewww.net/logs/{id}")
```

Comment: @ jon  since i'm fetching logs_id from the sql query  will  logs_id = [1,2,3,4 ] will it works

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_list.append('https://qwetest.seem.nsww-rdnewww.net/logs/' + str(logs_id[logs_id_counter]))
```

Comment: This above statement is giving error like this                             
                                                                                                   
 TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: along with above two statements these are remaning code  
   slug,id,reason in cur.fetchall():
   temp_list.append(str(slug))
   logs_id = id                                                 temp_list.append('https://rtest.sdm.nsn-rdnet.net/logs/' + str(logs_id[logs_id_counter]))
                         reason = str(reason)
                          temp_list.append(str(reason))
                          templine = ",".join(temp_list)                                            
                          f_out1.write( templine + '\n' )

Comment: `temp_list.append('rtest.sdm.nsn-rdnet.net/logs/'; +str(logs_id[logs_id_counter])) ` why `;` ??